# Inner join based on specific condition

Tags: mysql, sql

Tables are as follows:

**Tb_RefCity**
(both columns varchars)

```
RealCity    |   RefCity
------------------------
London        00 Perfor-Lon
Amsterdam     Ort Amster
```

**Tb_RawData**
(both columns varchars)

```
Counter     |   FakeCity
------------------------
222234      |   00 Perfor-Lon (2342)
342344      |   00 Perfor-Lon(23L)
534534      |   00 Perfor-Lon (342211
234444      |   Ort Amster(761)
234234      |   Ort Amster L1)
```

I want to inner join Tb_RawData with `Tb_RefCity` to insert `RealCity` into `City` column and counter values to `Tb_FinalTable`

Result should look like this (example)

**Tb_FinalTable**
(Counter = int / City = varchar)

```
Counter     |   City
-----------------------
222234      |   London
342344      |   London
534534      |   London
234444      |   Amsterdam
234234      |   Amsterdam
```

**My current query:**

```
INSERT INTO Tb_FinalTable
SELECT Raw.Counter, Ref.RealCity 
FROM Tb_RawData As Raw 
INNER JOIN Tb_RefCity As Ref ON Raw.FakeCity = Ref.RefCity
```

**Problem:**

The problem is in `Tb_RawData` `FakeCity`'s could have diffrent ending strings, however starting point is always the same for specific city e.g :

```
00 Perfor-Lon
Ort Amster
```

I would like my query to be independent for ending strings in `FakeCity` and in inner join to check starting strings comparing with Ref table to get real city. Hope you get my point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cae0da/1

```
INSERT INTO Tb_FinalTable
SELECT Raw.Counter, Ref.RealCity 
FROM Tb_RawData As Raw 
INNER JOIN Tb_RefCity As Ref 
ON Raw.FakeCity LIKE CONCAT(Ref.RefCity,"%");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT Raw.Counter, Ref.RealCity FROM Tb_RawData As Raw INNER JOIN Tb_RefCity 
As Ref ON Raw.FakeCity LIKE CONCAT(Ref.RefCity, '%')
```